# Converting local time to UTC in snowflake

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have sample data as follows:

```
ship_id | origin_zone |  dt_local
 1234   | Asia/Taipei| 2022-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

The goal is to convert `dt_local` into UTC. Here is my SQL for that:

```
select 
   origin_zone,
   dt_local,
   convert_timezone('UTC', origin_zone, dt_local) as utc_time
   
from table;
```

Please see the screenshot for the output. It seems it is just adding an offset of 8 hours to this time, which doesn't sound true. Taipei is 8 hrs ahead of UTC, so I am expecting it to subtract 8 hours from `dt_local` column.

I think that because I'm running this query in America/Los Angeles time (which is 8 hrs behind UTC), it's just adding 8 to the `dt_local` time column.

Can I please get some help on how to get the correct UTC time for this column?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the source and target timezones reversed. It should be:

```
select 
   origin_zone,
   dt_local,
   convert_timezone(origin_zone, 'UTC', dt_local) as utc_time
   
from table;
```